# Is it possible to apply a change event to a substring of a value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm building a credit card form for a client and want the credit card company logo to appear once the person starts typing their credit card number.

All Visa's start with 4.  MC with 5.  Discover with 6.  Amex 36, Diners 37.

So I'm trying something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $($('#cardNumber').val().substring(0,1)).change(function() {
            switch ($(this).val()) {
                case '4':
                    $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/visa.png" alt="Visa" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/mastercard.png" alt="Mastercard" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                    break;
                case '6':
                    $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/discover.png" alt="Discover" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="creditCardForm" id="creditCardForm" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="cardNumber">Card Number:</label>
        <span id="cardImage"></span>
        <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

...whereas I'm trying to apply a change function to just the first character in the value.  Is something like this possible?

**--UPDATE--**

Based on the comment below, I modified the form to have a hidden field that contains just the first number entered.  The problem I'm encountering now is that the keyup is not triggering a change on the hidden field.  Chaining a .change() function to the end of the hidden field triggers the image to appear every time.  I don't want to un0bind the event after the first digit is typed in case the user goes back and modifies the first digit again.

Any thoughts on a way to proceed here?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cardNumber').on('keyup', function() {
            $('#firstCreditCardDigit').val($(this).val().substring(0,1));
        });

        $('#firstCreditCardDigit').change(function() {
            switch ($(this).val()) {
                case '4':
                    $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/visa.png" alt="Visa" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/mastercard.png" alt="Mastercard" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                    break;
                case '6':
                    $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/discover.png" alt="Discover" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="creditCardForm" id="creditCardForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstCreditCardDigit" id="firstCreditCardDigit">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="cardNumber">Card Number:</label>
        <span id="cardImage"></span>
        <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: No, the event applies to the element, not the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like `on("propertychange keyup input cut paste", function(ev){}` instead, you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/P8GD3/3/):

```
$('#cardNumber').on("propertychange keyup input cut paste", function (ev) {
    if ($(this).data("done") != $(this).val().substring(0, 1)) {
        switch ($(this).val().substring(0, 1)) {
            case '4':
                alert("4")
                break;
            case '5':
               alert("5")
                break;
            case '6':
                alert("6")
                break;
        }
        $(this).data("done", $(this).val().substring(0, 1))
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).data("done", false)
});
```

Comment: This is close... but it doesn't take into consideration if a value already exists.  For example, I want someone to be able to enter a number, change their mind and enter a different number without having to blank the field.  IE: Someone types in a Visa number, then goes back and changes the 4 to a 5.

Comment: oh I see, let me think about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Events are applied to elements, contents can only be validated.
You can try something like this,it will work even if someone type 4111 1111 1111 1111 and later change 4 to 5

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cardNumber').change(function() {
                var firstDigit= $(this).val().substring(0, 1);
                switch (firstDigit) {
                    case '4':
                        $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/visa.png" alt="Visa" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/mastercard.png" alt="Mastercard" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        $('#cardImage').hide().html('<img src="img/discover.png" alt="Discover" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">').fadeIn(250);
                        break;
                }

            });
});
```